# My table view cells are not being populated

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have read many other posts about this issue, but those solutions haven't been able to fix my issue. Here is my storyboard:

[image: Story board]

The only screen that matters is the bottom screen (Dining Hall Feed View Controller)
The other login/sign-up screens segue into the Dining Hall Feed.

Dining Hall Feed View Controller has a table view with a prototype cell. That cell has a UIImageView, and two labels (Dining Hall Name and Description).
I made sure to create a new swift file that is a subclass of UITableViewCell and connected those outlets (UIImageView, UILabel). I also made sure to link the prototype cell to DiningHallCell and made those changes to the identifier:

[image: Class]

[image: Identifier]

Here is the code for my DiningHallFeedViewController:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Alamofire

class DiningHallFeedViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var diningHalls = [PFObject]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        //tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DiningHallCell")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        let query = PFQuery(className:"DiningHall")
        query.includeKeys(["diningHallName", "description", "image"])
        query.limit = 10
        
        query.findObjectsInBackground { (diningHalls, error) in
            if diningHalls != nil {
                self.diningHalls = diningHalls!
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            } else {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return diningHalls.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DiningHallCell") as! DiningHallCell
        
        let diningHall = diningHalls[indexPath.row]


        /* This is what the cell should be populated with, but it comes out empty*/

        cell.diningHallName.text = diningHall["diningHallName"] as? String
        cell.diningHallDescription.text = diningHall["description"] as? String
        
        // cell.diningHallName.text = "test"
        // cell.diningHallDescription.text = "test desc"

        print(diningHall)
        
        return cell
    }
    
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */
    
    @IBAction func onLogout(_ sender: Any) {
        // Code to log out
    }
    

}
```

I know that I am properly querying the data because when I print the diningHall, I get back all the proper data. I also tried doing dummy tests that still don't populate the table view.

This is my output:

[image: output]

Do I need to add a "tableView.reloadData()" somewhere? I do that when we query it, but I don't know where else to put it. I tried putting it in the viewDidLoad() function, but that didn't work.

EDITED:

I added this line of code to print out the diningHall (the data):

```
/* in the cellForRowAt tableview function */
print("This is the data: ", diningHall)
```

This is one of the outputs:

```
/*
This is the data:  <DiningHall: 0x600001fb1860, objectId: hPM1yo2hXs, localId: (null)> {
    description = "A modern eatery featuring an open kitchen, sushi bar, and an exciting Pacific Rim-inspired menu. Our chefs draw from various Asian cultures to serve up the freshest seafood, crisp greens, local produce inspired vegetarian fare, and noodle dishes. The ideal experience focuses on tasting a variety of flavors and sharing plates with friends.";
    diningHallName = Bistro;
    image = "<PFFileObject: 0x60000355c1e0>";
}
*/
```

This data comes from ParsePlatform, so I think the format should be a dictionary?

Comment: I would start by printing diningHalls.count in the numberOfRowsInSection method and see if you have the right number of rows. You could also set the number of rows to a fixed number as a test.

Comment: Thank you! that is a great start because I see that it starts at 0 twice and then outputs 10. In other words, it seems this function is called 3 times? It calls it twice and then I get this error: "2022-03-22 22:24:56.740412-0700 UCSD Food Review[85598:5072386] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(144) Failed to log metrics"
and then calls it again and returns 10. This makes me think that the table view might not be refreshing

Comment: Try to create the query in view will appear

Comment: And run reload data in main queue

Comment: show the format of data. Looking at your table seems like there are 10 items in diningHalls. But when you are assigning text to label, probably the format is wrong. Update your question with format of your data

Comment: I went ahead and updated the question. I'm pretty sure the data format comes in the form of a dictionary. But maybe it isn't because it seems that it looks like this: 
{
key = value
}

I'm still getting use to swift, but generally dictionaries are in the form: 
{
key: value
}

Slight difference, but the output seems to be using an "=" operator, so does this imply its not a dictionary and it is not in the correct format?

Comment: Also follow up to that, even if the data was in the right format, shouldn't it still be able to populate with something? I tried to write a fixed value for it and it wouldn't populate. cell.diningHallName.text = "test"